# How to assign equal scaling on the x-axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I currently have is this:

```
x = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 11.0]
y = [6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5]
```

Which produces the following graph:

[image]

What I'd like is to have equal scaling on my axis. Therefore, instead of having such a large gap between 7 and 9 and also 9 and 11, it'd be a space equal like all others. It's look like this:

[image]

To eliminate the 8 and the 10 from the graph I used ticks. Here is the relevant code:

```
ax=fig.add_subplot(111, ylabel="speed")
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo')
ax.set_xticks(x)
```

None of the examples on the [matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) have anything that I desire. I've been looking through the documentation, but everything 'scaling' related doesn't do what I want it to do.

Can this be done?

Comment: You could just plot against x = 3,4..9 and then change the 6th and 7th tick labels to '9' and '11'.

Comment: @Chris I guess, but that would only work in this situation. This is just a simple example, but the application will grow to potentially hundreds of numbers that are separated by much bigger spaces.

Comment: Are you x-values always going to be integers?

Comment: My comment is for the example you give in the question but it can also apply to the more general problem, if your x-coordinate is reasonably behaved. See my answer for one possible solution.

Comment: @tcaswell Yup, my x-values will always be integers (never doubles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to my comments to the OP, you can plot against the natural numbers 1 to n, where n is the number of unqiue abscissa values in your data set. Then you can set the x ticklabels to these unique values. The only trouble I had in implementing this is handling repeated abscissa values. To try and keep this general I came up with the following

```
from collections import Counter # Requires Python > 2.7

# Test abscissa values
x = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 11.0]

# Count of the number of occurances of each unique `x` value
xcount = Counter(x)

# Generate a list of unique x values in the range [0..len(set(x))]

nonRepetitive_x = list(set(x)) #making a set eliminates duplicates
nonRepetitive_x.sort()         #sets aren't ordered, so a sort must be made
x_normalised = [_ for i, xx in enumerate(set(nonRepetitive_x)) for _ in xcount[xx]*[i]]
```

At this point we have that `print x_normalised` gives

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
```

So plotting `y` against `x_normalised` with

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
fig=Figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

y = [6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 2.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5]

ax.plot(x_normalised, y, 'bo')
```

Gives

[image: Result of solution presented as plotted using matplotlib]

Finally, we can change the x-axis tick labels to reflect the actual values of our original x-data using [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) using

```
ax.set_xticklabels(nonRepetitive_x)
```

**Edit** To get the final plot looking like the desired output in the OP one can use

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = ax.axis()
x1 = min(x_normalised) - 1 
x2 = max(x_normalised) + 1
ax.axis((x1,x2,(y1-1),(y2+1))) 

#If the above is done, then before set_xticklabels, 
#one has to add a first and last value. eg:

nonRepetitive_x.insert(0,x[0]-1) #for the first tick on the left of the graph
nonRepetitive_x.append(x[-1]+1) #for the last tick on the right of the graph
```

Comment: +1 for a solution. I will keep the question open in case someone knows if matplotlib can actually do it itself. If not, then your answer is the best :)

Comment: Thanks. Matplotlib almost certainly cannot do this itself, since it only supports linear axis scales (with the exception of log scales) and you are wanting an arbitrary, non-linear x-axis scaling.

Comment: Any ideas how to do the last line (renaming the ticks) without `pyplot`, but `figure` instead? I initialized my figure using `matplotlib.figure` and ax using `ax=fig.add_subplot`. If I replace `fig=Figure(etc)` with `fig=plt.figure(etc)` (so I can now use `plt`), the site that uses these graphs can't load them anymore and just freezes =/

Comment: Have a look at the [matplotlib.axes API](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html), specifically the methods [`set_xticks`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) and [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! I did look at the API and previously tried set_xticks, but it wasn't what I wanted ( gave me http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6439/graphqg.png ). The labels one I hadn't tried because it seemed like it wanted text, but that's the one that works! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.