# Equal spacing between ticks of different values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077499/matplotlib-pyplot-plot-x-axis-ticks-in-equal-range) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045392/how-to-assign-equal-scaling-on-the-x-axis-in-matplotlib) and tried the methods mentioned there however, I got results that were totally different from what I am trying to do.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from collections import Counter


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title("Right Ear")


x = [125,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,6000,8000]

ax.set_ylabel("db HL")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
plt.axis([0,9000,130,-10])
ax.set_facecolor("#ffd2d2")
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(["","","500","","1K","","2K","","4K","","8K"])

ax.yaxis.set_ticks([120,110,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0,-10])

ax.plot()
plt.grid(color="grey")
plt.show()
```

Which gives this result:
[image: Unequally spaced grid lines]

I cannot figure out how to make the xaxis gridlines equally spaced like this:
[image: Equally spaced grid lines]

The methods that have been given in the above mentioned links gave me different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot you show has a logarithmic scaling with the base of 2; i.e. each tick is at the double of the previous one.
To set the scale to logarithmic with base 2, use `ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title("Right Ear")
ax.set_ylabel("db HL")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")
ax.set_xlim(100,9000)
ax.set_ylim(130,-10)
ax.set_facecolor("#ffd2d2")

x = [125,250,500,1000,2000,4000,8000]
ticks = [125,250,500,"1K","2K","4K","8K"]
xm = [750,1500,3000,6000]

ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticks(xm, minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels([""]*len(xm), minor=True)


ax.yaxis.set_ticks([120,110,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0,-10])

ax.plot()
ax.grid(color="grey")
ax.grid(axis="x", which='minor',color="grey", linestyle="--")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But this removes some values for which a label is not needed but just the gridline is needed.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to specify the ticks for which no label is needed as minor ticks, such that they can also have a different grid. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, they are equally spaced but you are plotting them with a logarithmic intervals, you should use a log scale.

```
import numpy as np


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
from collections import Counter


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_title("Right Ear")


x = [125,250,500,750,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,6000,8000]

ax.set_ylabel("db HL")
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency")

ax.set_facecolor("#ffd2d2")
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(120,9000)
ax.set_ylim(130,-10)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(["","","500","","1K","","2K","","4K","","8K"])

ax.yaxis.set_ticks([120,110,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,0,-10])

ax.plot()
plt.grid(color="grey")
plt.show()
```

[image]